# Número de itens para para substituir não é um múltiplo do comprimento do substituto

Tags: r

Estou tentando criar um método para a formula de minkowsky mas está dando esse erro. Acontece na linha em que eu tento atribuir o valor à `matriz_distancia[i,j]`.

```
distancia_minkowsky <- function(xtreinamento, xteste, r){
  matriz_distancia <- matrix(0, nrow(xteste), ncol = nrow(xtreinamento))
  for(i in 1:nrow(xtest)){
    for(j in 1:nrow(xtreinamento)){
      matriz_distancia[i,j] <- (abs(xteste[i,] - xtreinamento[j,])^r)^(1/r)
    }
  }
  return(matriz_distancia)
}
```

Eu havia tentado de outro jeito, fazendo `matriz_distancia[i,] <- formula`, mas a cada iteração era gerada uma nova linha inteira na posição i
Por exemplo, na primeira iteração do laço interno gera isso, para j = 10

> 4.680581
>   0.4122082
>   4.680581
>   0.4122082
>   4.680581
>   0.4122082
>   4.680581
>   0.4122082
>   4.680581
>   0.4122082

Na segunda iteração gera isso:

> 0.8917289
>   0.377533
>   0.8917289
>   0.377533
>   0.8917289
>   0.377533
>   0.8917289
>   0.377533
>   0.8917289
>   0.377533

Não entendi porque isso acontece, não estou familizarizada com o R. Está gerando valores repetidos

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ao fazer

```
matriz_distancia[i,j] <- (abs(xteste[i,] - xtreinamento[j,])^r)^(1/r)
```

tu está tentando colocar um vetor, que é o resultado da fórmula

```
(abs(xteste[i,] - xtreinamento[j,])^r)^(1/r)
```

dentro de uma posição dedicada a um número:

```
matriz_distancia[i,j]
```

Uma distância num espaço métrico é sempre um número real maior ou igual a zero. Portanto, a tua fórmula está incompleta. Faltou adicionar o somatório da distância de Minkowski. O código abaixo resolve este problema:

```
distancia_minkowsky <- function(xtreinamento, xteste, r){
matriz_distancia <- matrix(0, nrow=nrow(xteste), ncol=nrow(xtreinamento))
  for(i in 1:nrow(xteste)){
      for(j in 1:nrow(xtreinamento)){
          matriz_distancia[i,j] <- sum(abs(xteste[i, ] - xtreinamento[j, ])^r)^(1/r)
      }
  }
  return(matriz_distancia)
}
```

Comment: Muitíssimo obrigado! Ajudou demais :D